# Name change history

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page

It would be nice if there was something like a `name change history`. Many users change their display names and then it becomes difficult to recognise them. So having such a feature will be certainly helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Display changes are recorded, but your history is shown only to you, as of now. I see no harm in giving a user the option to make his username history publicly visible, but maybe thats just me. (PS: I'm not mimicking aking :P)

Enforcing public visibility would be considered a privacy infringement perhaps..

Comment: Display name changes are also shown to moderators. (This hasn't always been the case.)